# How to create a .mdf file without any authentication?

Tags: sql-server, wpf

I have to create a .mdf file of a database that does not require any authentication. I am using a .mdf file to attach the database to the application but the authentication restricts the application from running on machines other than the one it is developed on. Using a SQL user also fails as the application is unable to access the file.

EDIT
this is the error the OP is getting :

> Unable to open the physical file "~\bin\Debug\DB\Database.mdf".
>   Operating system error 5: "5(Access is denied.)

Comment: what authentication are you talking about ? Rights on the directory you want to create the mdf file ? Login to SSMS ? Something else ? Please explain in more detail

Comment: If you mean that you want to restore a database on an instance on which you have no rights (without authentication), that is not possible.

Comment: Is this a database on each client? LocalDB with integrated security might be the way to go.

Comment: @Andy Yes,this database is for each client. Tried LocalDB with integrated security. It runs fine on developer machine but an access error is shown for client machines

Comment: @GuidoG I created a database (for a desktop application) using SSMS. Now I have to attach the database to the application as a .mdf  file that can be packaged as a single installer package. But the .mdf file cannot be accessed as it shows an authentication error on client machines but it works fine on developer machine. Is there any way that I can create a .mdf file that can be accessed from any machine with a LocalDB support.

Comment: yes there is, it is what you are doing now it should work I have the same thing setup in one project. I believe I created an sql server login on that mdf file in stead of an existing windows user. Its been some time ago though might not remember exactly. Or just used windows authentication

Comment: can you show us the exact access error you are getting ?

Comment: Unable to open the physical file "~\bin\Debug\DB\Database.mdf". Operating system error 5: "5(Access is denied.)".   @GuidoG This is what I get when I tried after creating a new user for the  database that I use

Comment: it looks like the localdb driver and/or the application is run by a user that has not enough rights on the `~\bin\Debug\DB` folder or on the file. So I guess this is a local problem on each client with user rights

Comment: In other words, this is not an authentication error from localdb or sql server, but from windows

Comment: I have administrator privilege and is running the application in administrator mode

Comment: not according this error message. Can you check the explicit rights for any user for this directory and this file

Comment: also make sure this folder is not somewhere inside the `program files`folder from windows

Comment: The file has SQL server authentication activated but using a user id and password field is not clearing the error